# How to fix "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting" in connecting mongodb

Tags: mongodb, connection

I can't connect to the mongoDB, this is the error I'm getting each time:

```
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server started on port 5000
Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Already tried:
- changing ip access on mongoDB from everywhere to current ip adress and otherwise,
- creating new account that was for sure made on my current ip adress,
- disabling firewall,
- checked code for errors,
- tried restarting my pc for some reason

here is my code

```
//////server.js/////

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  res.json({ mgs: 'Welcome to the ContactKeeper API...' })
);

// Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/contacts', require('./routes/contacts'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

```
//////default.json/////
{
  "mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://artur123:<artur123>@contactkeeper-lv2py.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
}
```

```
//////db.js/////

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err.message);
      process.exit(1);
    });
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add your ip in the ip whitelist on mongoDB Atlas under :

Network Access

then restart.